# How to insert text in div without java-script or href to external file?

Tags: html

In my HTML file `example.html` I have:

```html
<a onclick="document.getElementById('D').innerHTML='some text'"> 
 clickme
</a>
```

where `D` is the id of some `<div>`.

So by clicking on 'clickme', `some text` is inserted in div `D`.

Is there a way to do this without using Javascript, and without using href to an external html file?
That is 'some text', the text to be inserted in div 'D', should be defined completely within my `example.html`.

Comment: HTML is static in nature, the only way to make changes to it interactively is using Javascript

Comment: @DevWithZachary  Static? With iframes it is possible to use href and insert text from an external source. I cannot understand why this cannot be done from within the same file!

Comment: Yes static, in that once the HTML code has been sent to the client's web browser it can't be changed. The only way to then make changes dynamically is with javascript. All an iFrame does is load the content of another webpage into the current webpage.

Comment: Perhaps show some example code of how you are doing this with an iframe as its not completely clear what your trying to achieve

Comment: why you like to complicate things, is simple with javascript. I can understand if you tell me, I don't want to use libraries like jquery, etc... if really want without also vanilla js, we can use some CSS (using ::before or ::after with some CSS combinators) but the result is not like js

Answer (score 1):

As some comments have said, yes, HTML is static by nature, but you can still accomplish this using css, because css has its own events an almost state management

I present two options:

#### 1. You can have your content hidden and then show it when click

explanation: we use a checkbox to emulate the button, then in css we see if the checkbox is checked then we make the content visible

#### 2. You can use pseudoelements to insert content using CSS

If you dont want this content in your HTML and you want to literaly insert it without JS, you can use a pseudoelement to "create" a new element and place it in your div (note the quotes there) so basically css will use a pseudoelement, but we use the same checkbox trick to let CSS handle the state and not need JS

As you can see it can be somewhat done, in the sense that you are adding content (to the users eyes) without javascript, but not without limitations:

#### Resources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

#### Working examples of both alternatives:

```css
/*hide the inputs/checkmarks and the content*/
input, .visibleAfterClick {
  display: none;
}

/*position the fake button*/
label {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px black solid;
  text-align: center;
}

/*show the hidden content when element is clicked*/
input:checked~div .visibleAfterClick {
  display: block;
}

/*'Insert' content when element is clicked*/
input:checked~div .InsertAfterClick::after {
  display: block;
  content: 'Content inserted after click';
}
```

```html
<h1>Option 1</h1>

<input id="check01" type="checkbox" name="menu" />
<label for="check01">Fake button</label>
<div>
Content always visible <br />

<span class="visibleAfterClick">
  Content visible after click
</span>
</div>

<br /><br /><hr /><br /><br />

<h1>Option 2</h1>

<input id="check02" type="checkbox" name="menu" />
<label for="check02">Fake button</label>
<div>
Content always visible <br />

<span class="InsertAfterClick">
</span>
</div>
```